# How to use Vercel env variable in Gatsby js? (client side)

Tags: gatsby, vercel

What I'm trying to do is set up dev/staging with Vercel, so I need to use staging keys for my Gatsby app (client-side).

**What I have tried:**

- Add environment `Preview` variable from Vercel project settings and connect Gitlab for integration. Then push test commits in `dev` to test if env is working, but it did not.

This should work base on this thread: https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/2613#issuecomment-594036619

- Use Vercel CLI to deploy, it was able to expose the environment variable but it uses the production variables. I believe it's because from Build step `npm run build`. but then how should I expose staging env?

Any leads will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Did you read Gatsby's [Environment Variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) guide? There's a [section about custom environments](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#additional-environments-staging-test-etc), beyond the default `development` and `production`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to fixed by adding `GATSBY_` prefix to my `Preview` environment variable in Vercel

in client-side you can access it as

```
process.env.GATSBY_YOUR_ENV_VAR
```